# Does anyone know what type of Cocoon this is?

Tags: entomology

[image]

I am really concerned with this since I've never seen a cocoon this color before and can't find it anywhere on the internet. I found it just laying on the ground not attached to anything, but it seems to be alive because when you touch it, it will wiggle abit. Any answers are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you keep it in a box or something, you might have better luck identifying whatever comes out. It probably won't be anything dangerous.

Comment: Adding your location could help a big time identifying

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found your cocoon: it appears to be a [Magpie Moth](http://www.bugsandweeds.co.uk/moths%20p1.html) (Abraxas grossulariata) cocoon:

[image: asqw[]  [image]

According to [UK Moths](http://www.ukmoths.org.uk/species/abraxas-grossulariata/), it's common in the UK.

Comment: I don't usually do this, but if you think this answer is correct, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it. Since it's so old, I don't think you'll get a lot of other answers.